# Whats the difference between format and Format?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use "Format" in the editor but every time I try, the editor auto correct it to "format" thus causing error when compiling. Any ideas?

```
Public Const DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"


dim timestamp as string
timestamp = format(Now, myModule.DateFormat) & "." & Right(format(Timer, "#0.00"), 2)
```

Comment: you only need 1 `=` not two.  I assume that's a typo.

Comment: It probably means that you have defined `format` variable/procedure/function somewhere in your code.

Comment: Add `Option Explicit` to the very top of your sub. As @BrakNicku you probably declared a variable `format` somewhere...which is not the best idea since that's a reserved word in VBA, hence your question.  Similarly, don't use `Cells` or `Rows` as variable names too, since those are also reserved words.

Comment: Also don't use `time` as it's another reserved word...

Comment: @BrakNicku that's exactly what happened. Looking through someone else's code revealed "format" was a sub routine which caused the error. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA isn't case-sensitive at all, `format` refers to the `VBA.Strings.Format` function regardless of its casing.

You have a variable or parameter or method *somewhere* in your project that looks like this:

```
Dim format As String
```

Change it to this:

```
Dim Format As String
```

And then the VBE will adjust the case of anything called `Format`, including in built-in referenced libraries.

At the end of the day it has no effect whatsoever, except being annoying. The only solution to this is clever naming.

Naming things is hard. Naming things in a case-insensitive language is even harder.

---

Whether the code compiles and runs correctly depends on the scope of whatever you have named `format`. If `format` isn't accessible from the code you've posted, then `format` resolves to `VBA.Strings.Format` regardless:

[image: works]

If, on the other hand, `format` is in scope, then you have a clash, and your code is calling that `format` method/constant/local/whatever, very likely in an illegal way.

Comment: _At the end of the day it has no effect whatsoever, except being annoying_. It has an effect - scope of `format` variable makes `Format` function inaccessible, unless you use full `VBA.Strings.Format`, and that is why OP's code didn't compile.

Comment: @BrakNicku Absolutely not. OP's code didn't compile because `time = = foobar` is invalid code. VBA is not case sensitive. That means `format` and `Format` are **identical** as far as VBA is concerned.

Comment: I cannot agree, if you fix double `=`, you will still receive `Expected array` error in this line. And of course both are identical, but it's the matter of scope

Comment: And now move `format` declaration to the same module.

Comment: @BrakNicku - It doesn't matter.  The only scope that breaks it is if it's in procedure scope.

Comment: @Comintern no, if it's in the same module - no matter if it's local or global variable, the code won't compile.

Comment: @BrakNicku correct. I also say exactly that below the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, that's all I wanted to say in my first comment:) You already have my upvote and I'll delete my comments soon to remove noise.